# Getting a 403 response code error from ExoPlayer

Tags: android-tv, exoplayer

I am randomly getting 403 error from google DAI url. Sometime no issue the whole day. Sometime it happens when start playing, sometime it happens after several minutes playing. This happens on live streaming and full screen live streaming.
Here are the logs:

```
onLoadError() called with: eventTime = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsListener$EventTime@c2e375b], loadEventInfo = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$LoadEventInfo@fed7bf8], mediaLoadData = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$MediaLoadData@db388d1], error = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403], wasCanceled = [false]
ExoAnalyticsLogger: onLoadStarted() called with: eventTime = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsListener$EventTime@bc71f36], loadEventInfo = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$LoadEventInfo@90eee37], mediaLoadData = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$MediaLoadData@d7a5fa4]
ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
                                                                          com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:267)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:214)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
ExoAnalyticsLogger: onLoadError() called with: eventTime = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsListener$EventTime@65df8c2], loadEventInfo = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$LoadEventInfo@fda36d3], mediaLoadData = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSourceEventListener$MediaLoadData@6cfd210], error = [com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403], wasCanceled = [false]

Encountered error
                                                                          com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:349)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                           Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:267)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:214)
                                                                              at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 3):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3472), there might be an issue with the cookie handler/manager. Make sure that you are using the same `CookieHandler` in both your `okhttp` service class and the exo player activity. You may also check this [link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/625) for additional reference.

Comment: i am not using the cookie handler at all, also the url from the server is not sending with cookies, i even tried with the cookie handler with same example as you mentioned in the comment, it didn't fix the issue and i was getting the null. 
Secondly as your mentioned example, my problem is different, It is the case, where my live stream runs for hours, even  days continuously but suddenly it shows this exception, and when i restart it, its start working as usual.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm also stuck with this 403 issue. I'm trying play live channels HLS. With HD channels it plays properly but with SD channels, it will play for 1 min and then freez with 403 error.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm also having this very same issue. Would play for 10 seconds and then freeze when trying to to go to higher bitrate.

Comment: Any update on this? I also have same issue Response code 403

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4320) thread regarding storing cookies. Assuming you're streaming with Akamai url, the solution solved the 403 issue for me.

Note you'll need to implement

- `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.6.0`
- `com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.11.4`

to get JavaNetCookieJar and OkHttpDataSourceFactory.